# MS Teams adaptive card "herocard" not work on mobile

Tags: javascript, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I`m creating bot for MS Teams and using **JS** **Microsoft Bot Framework V4 SDK**.
In my work, I use search message extension and to work with it, I implemented the **onSelectItem** method that returns a adaptive card. I will give an example of the code below.

```js
    return Promise.resolve({
      type: "result",
      attachmentLayout: "list",
      attachments: [CardFactory.heroCard(
        `${file.name}`,
        `${text}`,
        undefined,
        CardFactory.actions([
          {
            type: "openUrl",
            title: "Open",
            value: `${openLink}`
          },
          {
            type: "openUrl",
            title: "Download",
            value: `${downloadLink}`
          },
        ]),
      )]
    });
```

Where I pass undefined, this should be the path to the picture, but in my implementation I don't need it. So and this code works great in the browser and on the desktop version here is a screenshot

[image]

however, on the mobile version, I get the following result

[image]

this is absolutely not the right card, it has no content or buttons

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer myself. When the message extension search is triggered, the **onQuery** method is called and suppose you made a query and received an array of values ​​that you want to display. And here, in the same method, iterating over the array, you must draw two cards at once. For example

```js
files.forEach((file: IDocumentInfo): void => {
      const card: any = CardFactory.heroCard(
        cutString(file.name, LIMIT),
        text,
        undefined,
        [
          {
            type: "openUrl",
            title: "Open",
            value: "", // some value
          },
          {
            type: "openUrl",
            title: "Download",
            value: "" //some value,
          },
        ]
      );

      const preview: any = {
        contentType: "application/vnd.microsoft.card.thumbnail",
        content: {
          title: `${cutString(file.name, LIMIT)}`,
          text: "", // some text
        }
      };
```

And here the variable **preview** in my case will respond to a small view of information after the search and the variable **card** will be responsible for the view after selection. And after the card is selected, the **onSelectItem** method is triggered, which I need to get more information about the document

It turns out that the adaptive **heroCard** is not to blame here, the **onSelectItem** method is not called in the mobile application, or I am doing something wrong